# Window popup close and refresh the parent page on successful login Facebook

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, facebook, codeigniter

I'm done on the login with social network sites but I'm having a trouble of how can I make my popup window close and refresh the parent page upon a successful login

here's is my current approach (This may not help you but I just want you to know that I have done my job) This is my JS:

```
    function PopupCenter(url, title, w, h) {  
        // Fixes dual-screen position                         Most browsers      Firefox  
        var dualScreenLeft = window.screenLeft != undefined ? window.screenLeft : screen.left;  
        var dualScreenTop = window.screenTop != undefined ? window.screenTop : screen.top;  

        width = window.innerWidth ? window.innerWidth : document.documentElement.clientWidth ? document.documentElement.clientWidth : screen.width;  
        height = window.innerHeight ? window.innerHeight : document.documentElement.clientHeight ? document.documentElement.clientHeight : screen.height;  

        var left = ((width / 2) - (w / 2)) + dualScreenLeft;  
        var top = ((height / 2) - (h / 2)) + dualScreenTop;  
        var newWindow = window.open(url, title, 'scrollbars=yes, width=' + w + ', height=' + h + ', top=' + top + ', left=' + left);  

        // Puts focus on the newWindow  
        if (window.focus) {  
            newWindow.focus();  
        }  
    }
```

My HTML:

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url()?>hauth/login/Facebook" target="popup"  onclick="PopupCenter('<?php echo base_url()?>hauth/login/Facebook','xtf','900','500');   return false;">
```

And to identify if the user is connected (Located on Hauth/login controller)

```
if ($service->isUserConnected())
{
    log_message('debug', 'controller.HAuth.login: user authenticated.');
    $user_profile = $service->getUserProfile();
    log_message('info', 'controllers.HAuth.login: user profile:'.PHP_EOL.print_r($user_profile, TRUE));
    $data['user_profile'] = $user_profile;
    $this->load->view('hauth/done',$data);
}
else // Cannot authenticate user
{
    show_error('Cannot authenticate user');
}
```

Comment: before closing the pop up  you can do window.opener.location.reload(); na

Comment: @Plum That's my problem I don't know how can i use that and where to put it in

Comment: how you are closing the popup page

Comment: None. I haven't done anything because I don't know how and that is what I asked for.

Comment: may be there should be a close button inside the pop up page and the when you click on it trigger window.close(); window.opener.location.reload();

Comment: but how i can make it on successful login only

Comment: Why can't you make it on successfull login. you can do like this na if($login=='success'){ echo '<script>window.close(); window.opener.location.reload();</script>'}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105429/discussion-between-jonas-dulay-and-plum).

Comment: FYI: If you use the JS SDK for login, you get that functionality “built-in” already.

Answer (score 0):

Add like this in your view page:-

```
 if($user_profile) echo '<script>window.close();
        window.opener.location.reload();</script>';
```